# C# Linq create a list of derived class inside Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method in which I call a method that performs a query returning an IEnumerable of objects, then I perform a group by Linq on this IEnumerable, and elaborate the result of the grouping to insert it in a JQGrid. In the grouping, I create an object containing a list of other objects. I want that this list is not of the base type, but I would like it to be of the derived type.
This is the call to the method that performs the query, returning the IEnumerable object:

```
IEnumerable documentList = ObjBase.getAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnList) ? null : columnList.Split(';'), sidx, sord, sqlWhere, out totalRows, userid: userId, siteId: siteId);
```

This is the class of objects that I have after the group by Linq:

```
public class DocumentContact : ObjBase
{
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID { get; set; }
    public long? CODE_CONTRACT_ID { get; set; }
    public long CODE_SITEID { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_STATES { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentModelDates> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

This is the DocumentModel class:

```
public class DocumentModel : ObjBase
{
    private long _id;
    private string _documentModel;
    private long? _documentModelTypeId;
    private long? _documentModelIssuingEntityId;
    private string _documentModelFilename;
    private string _documentModelPath;
    private DateTime? _documentModelStart;
    private DateTime? _documentModelEnd;
    private string _documentModelVersion;
    private long _contractId;
    private string _contractNumber;
    private long _contractTypeId;
    private long _contractStateId;
    private string _contractState;
    private long _documentModelStateId;
    private string _documentModelValoId;
    private DateTime? _documentModelUploadDate;
    private byte[] _documentModelContent;
    private long _documentModelFilter;
    private bool _flagDeleted;
    private long _userId;
    private int _orderDocumentModel = 0;
    private string _placeOfIssue;
    private string _issuingEntity;
    private DateTime? _releaseDate;
    private int? _idOpInsert;
    private int? _idOpId;
    private long? _customerId;
    private long? _customerTypeId;
    private string _customerNumber;
    private DateTime? _documentModelInvalidated;
    private bool _flagValidating;
    private string _fileRemotePath;
    private long? _folderId;
    private string _folderName;
    protected new HELPSI_Database HELPSI_Database = Common.HELPSI_Database.HELPSI_Anag;
}
```

This is the DocumentModelDates, derived from DocumentModel:

```
    public class DocumentModelDates : DocumentModel
{
    public long? DateStart { get; set; }
    public long? DateEnd { get; set; }
    public long? DateUpload { get; set; }

    public DocumentModelDates(DocumentModel document)
    {
        this.CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID = document.CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID;
        this.DateStart = document.DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START.Value.Ticks;
        this.DateEnd = document.DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END.Value.Ticks;
        this.DateUpload = document.DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD.Value.Ticks;
    }
}
```

This is the Group By Linq operation on these IEnumerable:

```
    var documentContact = documentList.GroupBy(c => new
    {
        c.CODE_CUSTOMERID,
        c.DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER,
        c.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID,
        c.CODE_CONTRACT_ID, 
        c.DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
        c.DESC_CONTRACT_STATES,
    })
    .Select(gcs => new DocumentContact()
    {
        CODE_CUSTOMER_ID = gcs.Key.CODE_CUSTOMERID,
        DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER,
        CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID = gcs.Key.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID,
        CODE_CONTRACT_ID = gcs.Key.CODE_CONTRACT_ID,
        DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
        DESC_CONTRACT_STATES = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTRACT_STATES,
        CODE_SITEID = siteId,
        Documents = gcs.ToList(),
    });
```

If I do this, I have a conversion error: Is there a way to create a DocumentModelDates list inside this Select? Thanks.

Comment: Just try `Documents = gcs.Select(i => new DocumentModelDates(i)).ToList()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need:

```
.Select(gcs => new DocumentContact()
{
    //...
    Documents = gcs.Select(i => new DocumentModelDates(i)).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
   public class DocumentModelDates
    {
        private DateTime _DateStart { get; set; }
        public long DateStart
        {
            get { return _DateStart.ToBinary(); }
            set { _DateStart = DateTime.FromBinary(value);}

        }
    }
```